# Python + Apache Mod_Wsgi unable to give response

Tags: python, apache, flask, mod-wsgi

I have developed a web application in python.When i am executing that web application from SPYDER i am getting all the responses But the same web application when i had deployed in Apache it is not giving any response and it is not giving any error too....Just it showing loading symbol.I am not getting why and where the error is

Configuration in Apache:

```
<Directory C:/xyz>
    AllowOverride None
    Options None
    Require all granted
</Directory>
WSGIScriptAlias /xyz c:/xyz/xyz.wsgi
```

WSGI file :

```
 import sys
    #Expand Python classes path with your app's path
    sys.path.insert(0, "C:/xyz")

    from xyz import app

    #Put logging code (and imports) here ...

    #Initialize WSGI app object
    application = app
```

FYI 
There are four modules and each module has a method.All the modules and the Main Class are in the same folder "C:/xyz"

Comment: It looks like your Apache `.conf` file is wrong. Have you try this tutorial:
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-serve-django-applications-with-apache-and-mod_wsgi-on-ubuntu-14-04. And don't forget to change your `wsgi.py` file

Comment: @AndMar Same Config File for other web applications are giving results

Comment: check path in config, I think there is issue, here is example https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/howto/deployment/wsgi/modwsgi/#basic-configuration

Comment: Set ``LogLevel info`` and then monitor the Apache error log to see if your request even makes it to Apache. If it does, try setting ``WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}``. See http://modwsgi.readthedocs.io/en/develop/user-guides/application-issues.html#python-simplified-gil-state-api